# SQlite pool connection inside node-api

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

when we use sqlite-pool for creating connection with DB , after establishing connection it creates two extra file .db-shm or .db-wal file, when we insert data via connection object it contains that data into .db-shm file, it doesn't insert data into actual .db file.

my code for connection  :

```
const sqlite3 =require('sqlite3').verbose();
const sqlite = require('sqlite-pool');
const Promise=require('bluebird');
var express= require('express');
var restapi = express();
    function setMultipleconnection(databasename)
    {
        var dbconnection;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            dbconnection = new sqlite('./'+databasename+'.db',{Promise, min : 2, max:100});
            resolve(dbconnection)
            if(dbconnection == null)
            {
                console.log("conection failure");
                reject('error not connect');
            }
        }).catch((error) => { })
    }
```

and for insertion :

```
    restapi.get('/userlogin/:user', function (req, res){
        //createTBL_M_COMPANY("mydbex");
        var str="insert into user(name, title) values('kumar','hello')"
    setMultipleconnection("mydbex").then((dbs)=>
        {
            dbs.transaction(function(transaction, err)
            {
                transaction.run(str).then((row)=> {
                    if(row==undefined)
                    {
                        res.send('Error');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        res.send("Success");
                    }
            }).catch((err)=> {
                        res.send({ success: "", error: err.message });
                });
            });
        });

    })
```

Comment: That's what [write ahead mode](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) does, yes. Data in the WAL log eventually gets moved into the main database file when it's closed or checkpointed. This is all completely transparent to your code that uses connections to the database; data in the log still gets returned in queries like normal.